# Не работает нажатие на кнопку?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

У меня есть форма с сабмит кнопкой, нажатие на которую должно выводить на новую страничку введенные данные. Но почему-то нет реакции на нажатие. Как это все пофиксить?

HTML:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
     <div class="demo-btns">
        <div class="info">
           <div class="buttons">
              <p><input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Name:" size="18" /></p>
              <p><input type="text" name="roomCode" placeholder="Code of the room:" size="18" /></p>
              <input type="submit" class="modal__trigger2" value="Join Room" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Контроллер:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string userName, string roomCode)
        {
            string data = $"Username: {userName}, Roomcode: {roomCode}";
            return View(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "нет реакции на нажатие" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: нажимаю на кнопку, ничего не происходит ( в консоли ничего нет, редиректа нет, брейкпоинт не срабатывает) @Igor

Comment: Подозреваю, что страница все-таки перезагружается, но выводится тот же самый View.

Comment: https://github.com/INTERNALINTERFERENCE/test если интересно, то вот @Igor